# Incompatible Type when using web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

I have to use a web service which returns a string as result, it gets some string parameters too, so all things i have done is as this:
1- I have added that service reference to my project.
2- I have created an instance of that service class
3- I have call a desire function within class instance

here is my code:

```
     MyServiceNS.PscoWSDLPortTypeClient mys= new MyServiceNS.PscoWSDLPortTypeClient();
     string res;
     res =mys.srvReq("11320000", "21310000", "13901009", "1", "3");
```

But the problem is when i call mys.srvReq i get an error as below:

> The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 572
>   bytes of the response were: ?xml version="1.0"
>   encoding="ISO-8859-1"?SOAP-ENV:Envelope
>   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>   xmlns:SOAP-

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the problem is with the WFC not supporting the ISO-88859-1 encoding.
The default WFC encoder only supports utf-8 and utf-16 encoding.

You can create a suitable custom encoder as per the msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx

And/Or modify this useful example
http://eclectrics.com/software/2009/09/getting-the-current-weather-conditions/